# How to use OpenGL to render 2D points on an x-axis timeline representing a wide time range?

Tags: opengl, graph, graphics, 2d, rendering

I'm writing an OpenGL 2D plotting application to visualize real-time data. The x-axis timeline represents time in nanoseconds, however, the application will be plotting data that is collected over minutes (where each data point's X value is represented with nanosecond precision, values reach 10 significant figures).

If I represent my world points in nanoseconds problems arise due to floating point's 32-bit precision limitations (especially when zooming-out to get a view that spans minutes of data points).

What's the best approach to render these data points in OpenGL that will allow me to effectively zoom in/out with no precision problems. The end goal is to have a graph that plots minutes of data points where one can zoom-in on a section at the "nanosecond" level or zoom-out and view all points at the "minute" level, and everything in between (microseconds, milliseconds, etc...).

Also, is this essentially a Level of Detail (LOD) problem?

Links to any references are very much appreciated.

Comment: +Close as too broad. It depends on the data ... is it 1D signal like pulses or analog, ...  something else ? also the rendered output is unknown do you have some screenshots?  ... usually you blend all the data points at the same place together to avoid flickering but yes LOD can speed this up considerably (if the signal is not changing once sampled)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to represent each point`s horizontal position as two `float`s, one of which would contain the number of *milli*seconds that passed since T<sub>0</sub>, and the second one will hold the point`s position inside a millisecond, from `0.0` to `1.0`.

Why milliseconds? Mainly because the standard OpenGL `float` (which is, effectively, 32-bit IEEE `float`) has a mantissa able to hold 24 bits, or ~16 million different values. Thus, breaking the time interval by a million pieces seems a reasonable choice, while the max resolution of 10<sup>–9</sup> of a second makes it obvious that the unit interval that needs to be broken down is a 10<sup>–9</sup> / 10<sup>–6</sup> = 10<sup>–3</sup> of a second.